# Opening Command Line ('cmd') From Explorer

Tags: command-line, windows-explorer

Say I want to go to my documents folder and open a cmd session that *starts* in that folder. How might I do that? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Windows 7 and Vista, hold shift and right-click in/on a folder.  You'll get a new context menu option called "Open Command Window here".

There is an eponymous [Windows XP PowerToy](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx) which adds exactly that feature to Windows XP.

Comment: You can also just shift+right click on the desktop or just on the background of a folder.

Answer (score 2):

The PowerToy will do it, but I prefer to use cmdopen, which can be found [here](http://code.kliu.org/cmdopen/).

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Address Bar of the window and type in `cmd` and it'll open a command prompt in the folder you're currently in. No need to install anything.

Comment: Didn't work for me...just opened up a search page in Chrome looking for cmd...

Comment: What OS are you running? This might be Vista/7 specific.

Comment: Running Windows XP

Comment: Yeah, just ran a virtual machine and tried it, this doesn't work in WinXP.